# Why does clearing a ListBox cause an app to crash with "Value does not fall within the expected range"?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, windows-ce

I've got this code to populate a list box with the values from a table:

```
private void PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTables()
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable#1");
    menuItemSEND_Deliveries.Enabled = false;
    menuItemSEND_Inventories.Enabled = false;
    try
    {
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable#2");
        if (listBoxWork.Items.Count > 0) // for some reason, this causes a crash when canceling out of a new delivery form
        {
            ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable#3");
            listBoxWork.Items.Clear();
        }
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable#4");
        if (!hhsdbutils.TableExists("WorkTable"))
        {
            String msg = HHSConsts.NO_CURRENT_WORK;
            listBoxWork.Items.Add(msg);
        }
        else
        {
            ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable#5");
            List<String> workTables = hhsdbutils.GetWorkTableNames();
            menuItemTopSend.Enabled = workTables.Count > 0;
            menuItemSEND_Deliveries.Enabled = workTables.Any(p => p.StartsWith("DSD"));
            menuItemSEND_Inventories.Enabled = workTables.Any(p => p.StartsWith("INV"));

            listBoxWork.DataSource = workTables;
            if (listBoxWork.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                listBoxWork.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String msgInnerExAndStackTrace = String.Format(
                "{0}; Inner Ex: {1}; Stack Trace: {2}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException, ex.StackTrace);
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("From frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable: {0}", msgInnerExAndStackTrace));
    }
} // populateListBoxWithWorkTableData
```

It runs on FormActivate. The first time it runs, when the app starts, it works fine, and I see the debug strings for #1, #2, #4, and #5.

The second time the method above runs -- after opening, then closing another form, with one item in the list box -- it crashes with the aforementioned "Value does not fall within the expected range" after hitting points 1, 2, and 3.

Based on which points are getting reached, it seems that the "listBoxWork.Items.Clear();" is the problematic line, as that's the one that is not hit the first time. Why would that be? Why does clearing a list box with one item crash the app?

### UPDATE

Changing my code from this:

```
if (listBoxWork.Items.Count > 0) // for some reason, this causes a crash when canceling out of a new delivery form
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable#3");
    listBoxWork.Items.Clear();
}
```

...to this:

```
if (listBoxWork.Items.Count > 0) // for some reason, this causes a crash when canceling out of a new delivery form
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable#3");
    listBoxWork = null;
}
```

...got rid of the "Value Does Not Fall Within the Expected Oven" error, but replaced it with an NRE.

Comment: That did the trick; if you want to make it an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the listBoxWork control using a DataSource, so you probably can't manipulate the items collection directly. Try setting it to null instead:

```
listBoxWork.DataSource = null;
```